# HTML5 responsive wrap curved text around an image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a text field that the user can change, that then creates a curved text banner around an image.  I want that image to sit flush against the text (so it should sit higher if the text was all dashes, for example).  How can this be done?

In the sample provided it is just a regular image, but in my real case I'm using a canvas for the image.  I thought I might be able to render the text onto another canvas and then find the pixels and move the image as needed, but that was quite difficult.  So I'm looking for alternative solutions.

Relevant fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m89xjor1/4/

```js
function update(input) {
  document.getElementById("banner").textContent = input.value;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', cursive;
  font-size: 70px;
}

div {
  width: 900px;
}

path {
  fill: transparent;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
}

img {
  padding: 0 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="textbox" value="Lorem ipsum" onkeyup="update(this)">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <path id="curve" d="M73.2,148.6c4-6.1,65.5-96.8,178.6-95.6c111.3,1.2,170.8,90.3,175.1,97" />
    <text width="500">
      <textPath xlink:href="#curve" id="banner">
        Lorem ipsum
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </svg>
  <img src="https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/c6704316-0c21-4b65-99cc-904d14e4d2d9/ddefgnl-c3f81a9d-0730-4519-a95e-7b81f6a33f06.png/v1/fill/w_1280,h_692,strp/kamata_kun_transparent_ver_7_by_lincolnlover1865_ddefgnl-fullview.png?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9NjkyIiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvYzY3MDQzMTYtMGMyMS00YjY1LTk5Y2MtOTA0ZDE0ZTRkMmQ5XC9kZGVmZ25sLWMzZjgxYTlkLTA3MzAtNDUxOS1hOTVlLTdiODFmNmEzM2YwNi5wbmciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9MTI4MCJ9XV0sImF1ZCI6WyJ1cm46c2VydmljZTppbWFnZS5vcGVyYXRpb25zIl19.satBQ6uEOxjtnQn2YYaoM00I1fQ03vsApBd8juLxEDM">
</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want? At a glance i would say just render the SVG image to the canvas using `ctx.drawImage(svgImage, x, y, width, height)`

Comment: I thought I was clear in the question.  I want the image to sit flush against the text in a responsive way.  Therefore, if the user enters "----------", then the image should move up to sit flush against that text.  If the user enters "________", then the image should move down so the image is no longer colliding with the text.